# When I upload my excel file as a csv file the date format changes from m/d/yyyy to d/m/yyyy. How do I stop this from happening?

Tags: excel, csv

For example:
As Excel File:
Date
12/7/2020 9:00 AM
12/7/2020 10:00 AM

After CSV conversion:
Date
7/12/2020 9:00 AM
7/12/2020 10:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do something with your regional settings that Excel referes to when either writing or reading your csv.
See how to access regional settings here:
https://resrequest.helpspot.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=279

Changing the default Date and Time format here might solve your problem.